# how to display images uploaded to cloudinary in react "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

as instructed here https://cloudinary.com/documentation/advanced_url_delivery_options#client_side_resources

I used fetch API for accessing .json file to display uploaded media but an error occurs "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

here's my code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(window.cloudinary.url("reactflix.json", {type: "list"}))
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result)
        },
        
        (error) => {
          console.log('error')
        }
      )
  }, []);
```

I also have tried

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://res.cloudinary.com/omama/image/list/reactflix.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result)
        },
        
        (error) => {
          console.log('error')
        }
      )
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Client-side resources](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/advanced_url_delivery_options#client_side_resources) (aka Resource List) are restricted by default and require a [Signed URL](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/control_access_to_media#signed_url_authentication) for access. Since you aren't using a Signed URL, the most likely reason for the 404 is that the setting inside your account is the default one hence this type is restricted.

You can check this by going to the Settings -> Security tab in your account and under the field "Restricted media types" ensure that the "Resource List" option is not checked. If it is, then you can uncheck that and Save the settings.

After doing that, you can test with a new tag which you haven't tested with before. This is because if the reason for the 404 was indeed the restriction then you may get a cached error response from Cloudinary. Testing with a new tag would ensure you don't run into this case.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find the cloud name "omama" and the tag "reactflix.json"?
You might want to check it.

Most times client-side requests are just simple URLs, so you don't need to check through your application, you could just access it in your browser but I recommend using Postman. If the URL doesn't return anything in your browser it counts as a 404.